# Exclude a class and all of its children

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am loading global CSS styles but I need them to **not** affect one part of the page and all of its subcomponents. There are some old information but is there a solution now when :not() is a [Level 4 selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#negation)?

Codepen example that is not working: https://codepen.io/LaCertosus/pen/PoaYeRj

I have a HTML structure that is not predefined, I do not know how many and what elements are around and inside the "red" element.

Visual example

[image: Visual example]

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="_filler">
        <div class="_filler">
            <div class="block">
                Should be red
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="child-lime">
            <div class="block">
                Should be lime
            </div>
            <div class="_filler">
                <div class="block">
                    Should be lime
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```scss
.parent:not(.child-lime) {
    .block {
        background: red;
    }
}

/* Block is an example, in reality we don't know the class name */
.block {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: lime;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

I have tried different combinations with :not() selector but with no luck. It works when I don't need to include all children.

Comment: how have you tried to include :not?

Comment: The first part of your second example is invalid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

add this into CSS file

```
.parent > ._filler .block {
    background: red;
    }
    
    .child-lime .block {
        background: lime;
    }
```

remove this from CSS file

```
.parent:not(.child-lime) {
    .block {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. _filler classes are there just for example and this solution requires that specific HTML sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be missing some details, but here's what gets you close (assuming you can't touch the underlying HTML)

```
.parent {
    div:not(.child-lime .block) {
        background: red;
    }
    .block {...}
}
```

There's an un-classed `div` element that turns red...but since your comments seem to require not touching the underlying HTML *and* using the `:not` pseudo, that's probably as close as you can get.

Comment: This does not work. I have a HTML structure that is not predefined, I do not know how many and what elements are around and inside the "red" element. That DIV was there on purpose.

Comment: Can you add a class to it? otherwise, :not will always select the un-classed div.

Comment: No, the structure is not known.